# ListItem is not working in .net 4.0 webform dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, webforms

I want to take the data from an XML file to print the list items in a dropdown in webform.
But it's not getting any value from it.
I don't know what's happening. I am new to .net 4.0.

Code in weform.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" DataTextField="CityName" DataValueField="CityId" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />

</div>
</form>
```

Code in the Code behind file.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            DataSet DS = new DataSet();

            DS.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("Countries.xml"));
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "CountryName";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "CountryId";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            ListItem li = new ListItem("Select", "-1");
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, li);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are not setting data source property of DropDownList

Comment: ^^^^ You need something like ````DropDownList1.DataSource = DS````

Comment: Thank You so much, My problem is resolved.